# Можно ли с помощью flex добиться поведения подобно таблицам?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Можно ли с помощью `flex` выровнять блоки в ряд таким образом, чтобы они заполняли всё пространство по ширине, при этом блоки были бы разной ширины в зависимости от контента, т.е. вели себя как ячейки таблицы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.fake-table{
  display:flex;
}
.fake-table__cell{
  flex:1 1 auto;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid;
  background-color:#cda;
}
```

```html
<div class="fake-table">
  <div class="fake-table__cell">asdasdasdas dasdasdasdasd asd asdsadasdasdas </div>
  <div class="fake-table__cell">asdasd a asda</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прикольно! ;) То что нужно, спасибо!